# EF está dando Timeout em uma query que deveria ser instantânea

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Quando rodo o SQL gerado pelo EF direto no SQLServer ele roda com menos de 1 segundo.

Quando roda pela aplicação ele da timeout pois demora mais de 30 segundos. Tenho visto muito desse problema na internet com chamadas de procedure, mas quando se fala em rodar um SQL eu não acho muita coisa.

Banco de dados SQLServer 2012, Entity Framework 6.

Segue tudo que eu tenho de informação:

```js
(from v in _db.VIDEO.AsNoTracking()
                      join cv in _db.VIDEO_CATEGORIA.AsNoTracking() on v.ID equals cv.ID_VIDEO
                      where cv.ID_CATEGORIA == codcat
                      orderby v.DT_INCLUIDO_BD descending
                      select

                      new VideoModel
                      {
                          ID = v.ID,
                          DURATION = v.DURATION,
                          SCREENSHOT = (v.ID_ORIGEM == NUMERO_4_TIPO_LONG) ? v.ScreenShotServer : v.SCREENSHOT,
                          URL = v.URL,
                          VIDEO_TITLE = v.VIDEO_TITLE,
                          DATE = v.DT_INCLUIDO_BD,
                          origemlong = v.ID_ORIGEM,
                          totalclicks = v.TOTALCLICKS
                      });
```

Isso é usado depois com o PageList, filtrando paginas de 120 linhas, então ele vai receber uma parte a mais no SQL:

Pego o SQL usando o log do proprio EF: `db.Database.Log = s => log.Debug(s);`

```html
2015-08-24 15:02:44,035  SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project1].[DURATION] AS [DURATION], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[URL] AS [URL], 
[Project1].[VIDEO_TITLE] AS [VIDEO_TITLE], 
[Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project1].[ID_ORIGEM] AS [ID_ORIGEM], 
[Project1].[TOTALCLICKS] AS [TOTALCLICKS]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[VIDEO_TITLE] AS [VIDEO_TITLE], 
    [Extent1].[DURATION] AS [DURATION], 
    [Extent1].[DT_INCLUIDO_BD] AS [DT_INCLUIDO_BD], 
    [Extent1].[ID_ORIGEM] AS [ID_ORIGEM], 
    [Extent1].[URL] AS [URL], 
    [Extent1].[TOTALCLICKS] AS [TOTALCLICKS], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN (4 = [Extent1].[ID_ORIGEM]) THEN [Extent1].[ScreenShotServer] ELSE [Extent1].[SCREENSHOT] END AS [C2], 
     CAST( [Extent1].[DT_INCLUIDO_BD] AS datetime2) AS [C3]
    FROM  [ricardocorpore].[VIDEO] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [ricardocorpore].[VIDEO_CATEGORIA] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID_VIDEO]
    WHERE [Extent2].[ID_CATEGORIA] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[DT_INCLUIDO_BD] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 120 ROWS ONLY 
2015-08-24 15:02:44,035  

2015-08-24 15:02:44,035  -- p__linq__0: '28' (Type = Int64, IsNullable = false)

2015-08-24 15:02:44,035  -- Executing at 24/08/2015 15:02:44 -03:00

2015-08-24 15:03:14,081  -- Failed in 30041 ms with error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

2015-08-24 15:03:14,081  

2015-08-24 15:03:14,081  Closed connection at 24/08/2015 15:03:14 -03:00
```

O `[Extent2].[ID_CATEGORIA]` que é usado no `where` é `bigint` , a variável que chega no EF no código é `long`. Por isso descartei problemas de tipos deferentes de variável com coluna.

A coluna de `[DT_INCLUIDO_BD]` tem um index criado só para ela.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual o tamanho de cada tabela? A princípio não há qualquer problema com o código.

Comment: Se a consulta demora para ser executada quando vêm da aplicação, tenta fazer o [SQL Server Profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/2387977) dela para descobrir a causa. Este problema de você não conseguir reproduzir rodando a consulta diretamente pode estar relacionada com cache do banco (tem [como limpar também](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1873064/2387977) e testar novamente a consulta)

Comment: Hoje a tabela de Video tem um milhão e meio de registros, a de video_categoria 4 milhões de registros.

Comment: O plano de acesso do SQL é ótimo, eu já fiz o teste, usa os índices e a PK. Nenhum problema nele.

Comment: Mas se está demorando no banco a consulta, alguma coisa existe de problema. Quem vai te ajudar a mostrar isto é o SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Então, eu verifiquei o plano de acesso pegando a query e colocando no Management Studio, e ele diz que o plano está bom, tanto que eu rodo ela lá e ela roda instantaneamente. Eu uso um servidor compartilhado, por isso não tenho acesso a tabela `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` que eu acredito seria onde ver o que foi executado pela aplicação (Não tenho certeza se seria isso).

Comment: Veja o [link que passei, método 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/2387977): _If you can't run your query directly (or your query doesn't run slowly when you execute it directly - remember we want a plan of the query performing badly), then you can capture a plan using a SQL Server Profiler trace._ Chegou a limpar o cache e testar a consulta novamente, só para garantir que não é cache?

Comment: Tentei colocar o comando de limpar o chace em uma procedure, mas mesmo assim não tenho acesso para rodar, quando ao Server Profile eu nem consigo logar nele por falta de acesso tb...

Comment: Não pode falar com o DBA/pessoa que tem privilégios para te ajudar? Há um limite claro onde pode ir, sem privilégios suficientes, para investigar este problema. Se não conseguir acesso a todas as ferramentas necessárias para realizar o seu trabalho, fica complicado achar a causa. Você poderia mostrar o plano de execução que já conseguiu?

Comment: Já tem um dia que eu mudei a paginação para 130 linhas, agora ele executa o SQL no servidor em 2ms, mesmo SQL só que no lugar de 120 está 130... Se resolver assim vou deixar dessa forma. Se voltar o problema vou tentar conversar com o DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para o caso apresentado na pergunta foi a troca da coluna que está sendo ordenada.

De:

```
ORDER BY [Project1].[DT_INCLUIDO_BD] DESC
```

Para:

```
ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] DESC
```

O que eu pude entender é que o plano de acesso usado pela aplicação ou pelo management são diferentes.
Por isso alterei o SQL em uma tentativa de fazer ele executar o mesmo plano de acesso das duas maneiras.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Esta informação será valiosa para os demais usuários. +1.